# How to get value from data set from based on characteristics shared with inputted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently experimenting with python databases, and requesting info them. I'm trying to check if a data set (csv file):

```
Keyword, Word_num
hello,3
yup,4
yup,5
```

shares words with an inputted string. Here's what I have so far.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

#creates data set
df = pd.read_csv('Keywords.csv', index_col = 'word_num')

print(df)

print('///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////')

#new string for used to check for similatiry
input = 'yup world earthlings'

input = input.split()

#checking for cells andy words in common with 'x'
df = df[df['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(input))]

print(df)
```

As of now, this only outputs data in the Panda data set form:

```
Keyword
1     yup
```

What i'd like to do is get my output to simply be the string being stored ('yup').

Comment: your `Keyword` column is all `ints` and does not contain anything in the input string

Comment: Lol woops that just a typo they should be switched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please share your question in a reproducible way so others can create your data, such as:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['hello', 'world', 'yup'], 
                   'Word_num': [3, 4, 5]})
```

Secondly, do not name any object with the reserved special keywords. `input` is a special term in Python that does user input. Hence, name your object `my_input` or anything ordinary like that.

```
my_input = 'yup world earthlings'
```

Now what you are trying to do is take each element of this string and check if they exist in the `Keyword` column of your `df`. Well just do a loop that does exactly that:

```
for x in my_input.split():
    if x in df['Keyword'].values:
        print(x)

# Output:
# yup
# world
```

Let me know if this helps or if you need further assistence.

Comment: Thanks! I have found a different way to solve the problem using Jaccard Indexes but I appreciate the help. Also, I have the csv file above so that anyone can reproduce the data.

Comment: @LorenzoBeronilla Glad to hear you solved the issue. Just FYI, sharing csv, image, txt or anything similar does not make the problem reproducible. It would be good if you share the Pandas code that one can just run and recreate your problem, instead of having to create your data structure from scratch.

Comment: The line "df = pd.read_csv('Keywords.csv', index_col = 'word_num')" is what creates the pandas data set. I don't know if this helps at all but if that's what you're referring to it's there. I new to this whole stack overflow thing so this is all very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
results = df[df['Word_num'].str.contains('|'.join(input))].values[0]
```

```
for result in results:
    # do something
```

Comment: This worked however now I'm only getting the first word that the csv and input have in common. Like if the input is "hello world" and my keywords are "hello" and "world" I only get the "hello"

Comment: Also, this might be asking for much, but how would I go about fitting this into an if statement, or for/while loop. I haven't been able to find a way to get a true/false output so that probably doesn't help.